# Doing python numpy similar operation in cpp xtensor

Tags: c++, xtensor

I am converting some python numpy code into C++ code using xtensor library. I am having some issues in indexing based operations. Here is the python code:

### Python code

```py
boxes = decoded_boxes[keep, :]
```

- `keep` is a numpy boolean array of dimension `[19248]`
- `decoded_boxes` is a numpy array of dimensions `[19248, 4]`
- `boxes` (output) if a numpy array of dimensions `[24, 4]`

I am not able to write equivalent code for this. I tried this but did not work.

### C++ code

```cpp
xt::xarray<float> b1 = xt::filter(decoded_boxes, keep); 
std::cout << "b1 shape = " << xt::adapt(b1.shape()) << std::endl;
```

gives only `{24}`.

Comment: I would consider this a missing functionality. I submitted this : https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/issues/2589

Comment: ok Thanks. There are many things missing in xtensor as compared to python numpy. I hope we may get those as well very soon.

Comment: Please submit issues (or PRs!) for things that you miss (that is true for any open-source library)

Comment: Hi @TomdeGeus , does xtensor having parallel computation as we have in python numpy? I could not find anything related to parallel computation.

Comment: A bit I think with TBB. But I'm not really following that to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around as follows:

```cpp
auto id = xt::arange(decoded_boxes.shape()[0]);
auto b2 = xt::filter(id, keep);
    
xt::xarray<float> b1 = xt::view(decoded_boxes, xt::keep(b2)); // shape 24, 4
```